# Can the accessed website detect if i'm using a Virtualized like machine vmware, vbox, etc?

Tags: cookies, vmware, virtual-machine, privacy

If i access an website, it can detect if im using a virtual machine ?

More specifically an Vmware image?

And if the website is able to..
How can i prevent it?

Thankful, Chinchila

Comment: While I expect a _browser_ won't tell a website if you're running virtualized or not, a _flash_ or _activeX_ or (probably?) _silverlight_ plugin or (possibly?) _java_ applet can tell when you're running virtualized. So be careful with your plugins.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Web servers can only tell details about the web browsers through their user agent string.  Unless you're using a special web browser (unlikely) that detects that it's running in a VM, then the web server shouldn't know.  In any case, UA strings are easy to change to whatever you'd like them to be, so you can always pretend to be something you're not.

Check out [this useful Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Comment: So if i use a normal browser without addons i cant be detected as using a virtual machine?
I already read on a website that they can see even my active username, computer name etc...
I was worried about it to, to let my pc name undetected too.

Comment: No, they shouldn't be able to see your username or computer name unless you have some evil plugins/extensions installed.  Typically, all the UA string will give is which web browser you're using, its version, and your OS version.  IE also sends your .NET version.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is not exactly correct.
This can sometimes be done even simply using JavaScript by detecting your screen resolution to detect a windowed operating system as explained here:
http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2009/04/detecting-vmware-with-javascript-or-how.html

or by detecting your MAC address (VMware uses fixed MAC ranges) as explained here:
http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/web-pages-detecting-virtualized.html

To circumvent these problems, don't use re-sized windows and change your machine's MAC address. There are other ways to detect you are in a VM using JAVA applets maybe ActiveX plugins and probably other things as well...

Comment: Pretty interesting. But you usually must opt-in to running Java applets and ActiveX plugins (or those are disabled entirely), and the screen resolution is just a heuristic (although a clever one). Every VM I've dealt with in modern times (I realize this answer is 2.5 years old) will adapt to your physical monitor size, and there is a wide variety of screen dimensions. I stand by saying that there isn't an _easy_ way for a web server to detect if you're using a VM.

Comment: There are probably other detection methods that are based on timing (some tasks are slower on VM) or somehow detecting machine frequency (http://www.securitygalore.com/site3/vmd1-advisory)

Answer (score 5):

There are few ways to determine whether you are on a Virtual Machine and  below are the most used

1. **Through WebGL**: WebGL is a Javascript API that comes with the browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox, etc. This will leak the GPU name and the Vendor name of the renderer. While using a Virtual Machine, It will leak different rendered data than while using the browser on a physical machine. For example, Google Chrome shows Renderer's name as "Google SwiftShader"(It is used on machines without 3D graphics hardware.), Firefox Shows the renderer's name as "llvmpipe"(This is also a software renderer). It will lead to understanding to the website that you are on a Virtualised Machine. For more information regarding WebGL Check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API).
2. **Through WebRTC**: It will leak the local IP address to the website(Tested on chrome) but firefox is not leaking somehow
   [image]
   Also, the Virtual box adds a string "VirtualBox" in the prefix to the webcam name. Suppose you are using a Virtual machine and gave webcam access to some website, it will be able to see the webcam name along with the prefix "VirtualBox”. To prevent that you can check this solution once (https://askubuntu.com/a/1357986/699463)

If you want to know more about this kind of leaks, then definitely use this website https://browserleaks.com/ to perform leaking tests like webrtc, webgl, and more. It will also show the ways to avoid this kind of leaks.